# Full Width Content in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the roots theme, I am new to bootstrap and this forum.

so far my header and nav are full width, with a stripe of colour across the page.

on the home page only, i want an image that spans the page, 
and then maybe different sections of colour.

I created a custom home page template, but when I put any content into it, it is constrained to the width of the page content.

my question is, is this being caused by the base.php, and if so, what can i do about it? if not how do i create full width sections?

Thanks in anticipation.

** in fact looking at the base php file, i see the whole site is wrapped in this

```
<div class="wrap container" role="document">
<div class="content row">
  <div class="main <?php echo roots_main_class(); ?>" role="main">
```

then the content,

the custom page has only this code in it (so far)

```
<div class="purple"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_theme_root_uri(); ?>/choir/assets/img/headimage.jpg"/>
```

and yet when I inspect the source, its inside another div with class of col-sm-12 
(can't show an image) 
where  is this code coming from?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are classes with appropriate names: span6, span12 etc.

Comment: thank you, could you be a little more specific? at the moment there is no class so I assumed it would not be constrained to anything and yet it is.

Answer (score 0):

these classes aren't in the update, however I fixed this problem - asked it a different way 
[Full Width colour sections but not full width page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325150/full-width-colour-sections-but-not-full-width-page-content)
thank you